# Configuring a Job in Eclipse or IBM RAD

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I have a Pure Java Process which needs to be run every day at certain time.

This is a temporary job, so i don't wanted to create a new environment to configure this job.

**strong text**
Is there any way to configure this batch at certain time in Eclipse or IBM RAD?

Is there any plug in available for that.**strong text**

Regards,
Lokesh.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no standard facilities available in Eclipse to support "run code X at time Y", so you need to turn to operating system facilities.

If you can make a simple program launchable with "java -jar" you have many options.  FOr Windows many different EXE-that-launch-jar products exist (we use winsw to launch java as services) and you can then use normal scheduling (e.g. at) to invoke your code.